# Properly sizing empty elements

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a UI for a database. It has three main components: The first element should be a scrollable listing of all categories, the second one a scrollable listing of all items of that category and the third a `JPanel` that will contain the actual data (currently only a placeholder, I will probably need to generate a HTML document for that).

I made the `Category` and Item classes extensions of `JButton`s, because that's the only use they'll have.

```
    JScrollPane catSelect = new JScrollPane();
    catSelect.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    catSelect.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

    JPanel csPanel = new JPanel();
    csPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    csPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(scale.width/1972*300, scale.height));

    JScrollPane recSelect = new JScrollPane();
    JPanel rsPanel = new JPanel();
    rsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    rsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(scale.width/1792*300, scale.height));


    JPanel view = new JPanel();
    view.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(scale.width-csPanel.getPreferredSize().width-rsPanel.getPreferredSize().width, scale.height));

    Category dc = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++){
        Category cat = categories.get(i);
        cat.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(scale.width/1792*300, scale.height/1120*200));
        csPanel.add(cat);
        cat.addActionListener(rsPanel); //action changes rsPanel content
        if(cat.name.equals("Default")){
            dc = cat; //will always be assigned
        }
    }
    catSelect.add(csPanel);

    for(int i = 0; i < dc.recipes.size(); i++){
        Recipe rec = dc.recipes.get(i);
        rec.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(scale.width/1792*300, scale.height/1120*200));
        rec.addActionlistener(view);
        rsPanel.add(dc.recipes.get(i));
    }
    recSelect.add(rsPanel);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    frame.add(catSelect);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    frame.add(recSelect);

    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    frame.add(view);
    frame.pack();
```

I'm trying to get a the three elements next to each other from left to right, but all I'm getting here is an empty (and incorrectly sized) window. If I delete this entire block, I get a proper `JFrame` that fills my screen. If I directly add the Categories to the `JFrame`, they are displayed but the Frame is downsized to contain the buttons. If I add the whole block, I get an empty `JFrame` with about 2/3 of my screens width and 4/5 of its height. It is very important the even the empty components (i.e. the view component) get displayed in full size.

I don't see why the components suddenly disappear when I add the `JScrollPane`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"I made the Category and Item classes extensions of JButtons, because that's the only use they'll have."* Use a factory method to produce them, don't extend them. General tips: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JScrollPane catSelect = new JScrollPane();
...
catSelect.add(csPanel);
```

Don't add components directly to the JScrollPanel. A single component can be added to the `JViewport` of the scroll pane.

This can be done when you create the scroll pane:

```
JScrollPane catSelect = new JScrollPane( csPanel );
```

or you can dynamically update the viewport of the scroll panel using:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( csPanel );
```

Comment: This does add one visible JScrollPane, namely the second Scrollpane recSelect. The Jbuttons aren't visible, but when I added a JLabel it worked, with the JLabel distorted way beyond the screen height.